# How to loop through object of strings with dates in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have object, keys are dates, before dot are months, after are years:

```
const dataObj = {
  '01.2015': 0.01,
  '02.2015': 0.10,
  '03.2015': 0.05,
  '04.2015': 0.25,
  // ...
}
```

the function takes two dates and return an array with objects containing values from the dataObj

```
interface Point {
  date: string;
  value: number;
}

type Digit = '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9';
type Day = `${Digit}${Digit}`;
type Month =
  | '01'
  | '02'
  // ...
  | '11'
  | '12';

type Year = '2015' | '2016' | '2017';
type DateString = `${Day}.${Month}.${Year}`;

type MonthDateString = `${Month}.${Year}`;

function count(firstDate: DateString, secondDate: DateString): Point[] {
 const result: Point[] = [];
 let currentDate = firstDate.slice(3) as MonthDateString;
 // loop through dataObj and push in result
 return result // [{date: '01.2015', value: 0.01}, {...}, ...]
}
```

How to loop through dataObj? I tried for loop

```
for(let i = currentDate; i !== secondDate.slice(3);  )
```

but have no idea what to do with final-expression, how to update counter variable, pass next key(string with date) from dataObj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some confusion in regards to the expected output. The function `count` needs to return a `Point` array which is an object array where each object has two props namely `date` (a string) and `value` (number, floating-point per inline-comments in the code).

It is assumed that the OP requires to find key-value pairs in `dataObj` such that the key (ie, month-year) is between `firstDate` and `secondDate` (which are parameters to `count` function).

Based on this assumption, the below code may achieve the desired objective (to generate an array of `Point` elements).

```
const isGreaterOrEqual = (dtOne: MonthDateString, dtTwo: MonthDateString) : Boolean => {
    const getYear = (dt: MonthDateString) : string => dt.slice(3);
    const getMonth = (dt: MonthDateString) : string => dt.substring(0, 2);
    return ((getYear(dtOne) > getYear(dtTwo)) ||
        (getYear(dtOne) === getYear(dtTwo) &&
            getMonth(dtOne) >= getMonth(dtTwo)
        )
    );
};

function count(firstDate: DateString, secondDate: DateString): Point[] {
 let beginDate = firstDate.slice(3) as MonthDateString;
 let endDate = secondDate.slice(3) as MonthDateString;
 return (
     Object.entries(dataObj)
     .filter(([k, v]) => isGreaterOrEqual(k as MonthDateString, beginDate) && isGreaterOrEqual(endDate, k as MonthDateString))
     .map(([k, v]) => ({ date: k, value: v} as Point))
    );
};

console.log(count( "01.01.2015" as DateString, "01.02.2015" as DateString));
```

TS Playground: [Link here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-1jiE2CdWkCO50VCq9gswUfh8ea7VWZ3YQ+h7dzhfW50AMgv643BZL+one+nuHvTLPS5vxEdvZ7RiBdmiMBgCgMxwBgUBAKgNU7DMGxoBZFhqxNOsrGFOAEKmQ0HQTFg3A8ABtABdAMYC9WAUiKMAWTmGC4KgFl00zbNcxgBAID1WMsOTfMyJgKwwHQw05ggVDwEE6xGKzKwc2dNiOKrLj2XzftB2Hdd0AwVCoCofjjSsCANSQVBMG-W8qBgyIZRHfCAGtTTCQiD39MVJWlWw5SVFVIjVGzWPYu1FOQiiLBZS8LxgFypUNWUFWVKI1X48SrFNXy5ICrFk2XdcqESBBsmsuyYAcpzNzweBDRYQqIhiXUwiMPzXHcSwso3X8gWDT0rCoSIQECNUIMsNUYAAIkodhqGRehhoapC8VNUbqF4NRprk2bAmXUIgA)

Answer (score 0):

Some examples below:

```
for (let key in dataObj) {
   console.log(key, dataObj[key]);
}

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(dataObj)) {
   console.log(key, value);
}
```

If you want to have and update counter variable:

```
let keys = Object.keys(dataObj);

for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    console.log(i, keys[i], dataObj[keys[i]]);
}
```